# Key defined in JSON not showing in Chrome console

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to display an image who's name is stored in a JSON file. If I manually type the path to the file it works fine but as soon as I try to use a variable to change the image to be displayed it doesn't return the image. Can anyone help?

```
 $.each(responce.products, function (key, val) {
        if (val.name.search(myExp) != -1) {
            output += '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 shoe">';
            output += '<img class="img-responsive" src="images/'+ val.imgName + '.png"/>';
            output += '</div>';
        }
    });
```

I think the issue might be with this line of code:

```
output += '<img class="img-responsive" src="images/'+ val.imgName + '.png"/>';
```

If I type out the path like:

```
    output += '<img class="img-responsive" src="images/filename.png"/>';
```

it works fine. When I checked the console log I don't see the imgName key defined but it's defined in my JSON file. Used a JSON validator and it says my syntax is valid.

JSON:

```
 { "products" : [
```

{
    "name" : "product name 1",
    "id" : "232626-040",
    "price" : "299",
    "color" : "black gold",
    "description" : "  ",
    "imgName" :"img name"
  },
  {
    "name" : " product name 2",
    "id" : "232626-050",
    "price" : "300",
    "color" : "white gold",
    "description" : "  ",
    "imgName" :" image name"
  },
  {
    "name" : " product name 3",
    "id" : "232626-071",
    "price" : "100",
    "color" : "white",
    "description" : "  ",
    "imgName" : " image name"

},
  {
    "name" : "product name 4",
    "id" : "232626-010",
    "price" : "100",
    "color" : "white grey black",
    "description" : "  ",
    "imgName" :"image name"
  },
]}

Comment: Use `console.log(val);` within your loop to inspect the element you are trying to access. `imgName` is probably undefined, i.e. missing in your object. At this point we can only assume what the problem might be. Feel free to provide a snippet of the actual JSON file.

Comment: I do see "undefined" showing up in the browser. here is my JSON file

Comment: You may want to use a clipboard service like pastebin.com to share the JSON snippet. Make sure to mask any personal information in your JSON if any.

Comment: Do you get the JSON data using $.getJSON or $.ajax or something like that, if yes, can you show us the request code.

Comment: I used $.getJSON. The request code is as followed:

Comment: $.getJSON( 'products.json', function (responce) {
     console.log(responce);
     var output;
     $.each(responce.products, function (key, val) {
      if (val.name.search(myExp) != -1) {
       output += '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">';
    output += '<img class="img-responsive" src="images/'+ val.imgName + '.png"/>';
       output += '</div>';
      }
     });
     
     $('.product-area').html(output);
 });

Comment: The JSON seems fine to me. Try `console.log(val);` and compare the object with the plain data.

Answer (score -1):

The each param is wrong, it just a index and element ,no the key value.
.each( function )
function
Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )

[jquery each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: What are you talking about? The element is the actual object with the properties used in the code.